# I have same PHP payment methods in 4 platform, what is the best way to manage credentials?

Tags: php

I have built 4 different platforms based on different frameworks, Laravel, OpenCart...
So basically I've implemented a payment method (our own custom paymetn method) in all of them, but suddenly we need to change the URL of the pamyent method's API, now I need to go to all 4 platforms and change that => Deploy... 
What's the best way to extract these creds...
including 1 config file or maybe having some kind of API which will return the config data ... :)?

What do you think?

Comment: If these platforms are on a shared space, you could have a file that contains your credentials. Be sure to restrict the rights to the minimal, set the owner to the server user.